# NVIDIA cuda memory trace generator

Tags: debugging, memory, cuda, nvidia

I am newbie in the world of GPU. So I hope I can get some help/hint from you guys.

I would like to generate the memory access trace for all the loads/stores of a CUDA application. I am wondering if it is possible to generate these traces with any of the NVIDIA tools. What I would like to have is to generate a trace which tells at each clock cycle which memory addresses are accesses for all the cores.

Thanks

Comment: The current NVIDIA tools do not support the feature you are requesting. Trying to trace every memory access would add significant overhead as you would have to trace NumSM accesses per cycle for LSU + 1/2 NumSM accesses again for texture. The trace would generate 1-2x additional memory writes for the timing, smid and address data. If you cannot statically define the output location the tool would also have to use atomics to control the output. The best that could be done today is to write a tool that instruments PTX.

Comment: @GregSmith Thanks for your useful reply. Let me explain what I would like to do and you might know what is the best option. I would like to write a cache simulator for the GPU while keeping everything to run on the hardware. Something like Valgrind for CUDA codes.

Comment: I would like for example to be able to change the content of the Device memory as well and more :D

Comment: @GregSmith: It would be great if you added that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current NVIDIA tools do not currently (05/2014) support the feature you are requesting. Trying to trace every memory access would add significant overhead as you would have to trace at a maximum rate of NumSM accesses per cycle for LSU + 1/2 NumSM accesses again for texture.

The trace would generate 1-3x additional memory writes for the timing, smid, operation type, and address values. If the tool cannot statically define the output location of each operation then tool would also have to use atomics to allocate space for the trace record.

The current options for collecting this information are

1. Instrument the source code. This is not transparent to the
   application.
2. Instrument the PTX. Frameworks such as [Panoptes](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2012/presentations/S0078-Panoptes-Binary-Instrumentation-Framework-for-CUDA.pdf) and [Lynx](http://gpuocelot.gatech.edu/projects/lynx-a-dynamic-instrumentation-system-for-gpgpu-computing/)
   may be helpful.
3. Run the application on a simulator. GPU Ocelot may already support this type of instrumentation.

I would encourage you to file a RFE through the NVIDIA Developer Program.

Using these methods you could get an ordered list of operations per warp. In options 1 and 2 you may also want to instrument barriers so you can order operations within a block.